# Passing info from a Form into a function React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am new to react and js and I want to create an edit form that contains some modifiable info, which can be later posted to an API using Axios. the thing is, that I do not enter my function when I click on my submit button, and I dont know if my form info is passed correctly to my edit function.

```
function EditJob (jobid, event) {
  console.log('editjob fired 1')
  console.log(jobid)

  const updateJob = {
    title: event.target.jobtitle.value,
    company_name: event.target.companyname.value,
    internal_code: event.target.internalcode.value,
    department: event.target.department.value,
    location: event.target.jlocation.value,
    tags: event.target.tags.value,
    benefits: event.target.benefits.value,
    description: event.target.description.value,
    requirements: event.target.requirements.value
  }
  return axios({
    method: 'put',
    url: '/api/jobs/update-job/' + jobid,
    headers: headers,
    data: updateJob
  })
}
```

```
export default function Jobs () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [jobs, locations, departments, tags, deleteJob, editJob] = useJobs()
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false)

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false)
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true)

  return (
    <>
   {jobs.map(job => (
          <>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Edit Job Position</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>

                <div className='container'>

                <Form onSubmit = {async () => { await EditJob(job.id); editJob() }}>

                <Row>
                  <Col lg={6}>
                    <Form.Group controlId='jobtitle'>
                      <Form.Label style={{ color: 'green' }}>Job Title :</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control type='textbox' defaultValue={job.title} name='jobtitle' required placeholder='Enter Job Title' />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId='internalCode'>
                      <Form.Label style={{ color: 'green' }}>Internal Code :</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control type='textbox' defaultValue={job.internal_code} name='internalcode' required placeholder='Enter Internal Code' />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId='department'>
                    <Form.Label style={{ color: 'green' }}>Department :</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type='textbox' defaultValue={job.department} name='department' disabled required placeholder='Enter Department' />
                  </Form.Group>

                  </Col>
                <Col lg={6}>

                  <Form.Group controlId='jlocation'>
                    <Form.Label style={{ color: 'green' }}>Location :</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type='textbox' defaultValue={job.location} name='jlocation' disabled required placeholder='Enter Location' />
                  </Form.Group>

                </Col>
              <Col lg={12}>
              <Form.Group>
                <Button style={{ position: 'relative', left: '295px' }} variant='success' type='submit'>Edit Job Position</Button>
              </Form.Group>
              </Col>
            </Row>
              </Form>
                </div>
              </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
```

the `updateJob` const is supposed to hold the info sent from the Form using `event.target` but I think I'm doing something wrong because I don't even enter the function and my page just refreshes when I click on the submit button. what is the correct solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of the form is to trigger a reload on click of submit button. You can prevent this behavior by using `event.preventDefault()` in the onSubmit method

```
<Form onSubmit = {async (event) => {
       event.preventDefault(); 
       await EditJob(job.id); 
       editJob() 
}}>
```

Comment: I get an "event is undefined error" though now, but why?

Comment: Have you defined it in the argument of function like `onSubmit = {async (event) => {`

Comment: update: I deleted "event" from edit job and it was fixed

Comment: Right your EditJob function wasn't passing the event.

Comment: excuse me another question: ```<Form.Control type='textbox' defaultValue={job.tags} name='tags' disabled required placeholder='Enter tags' />``` here my server returns a 400 error because ```tags: Array [ "Expected a list of items but got type \"str\"." ]```

Comment: how can I fix this or convert it to an Array?

Comment: I can't use ```{job.tags.split(,)}```

Comment: why can't you split if its a string?

Comment: it says job,tags.split(',') is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214979/discussion-between-james-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: could you please check the chat out?